# Joomla Session Management

Tags: session, cookies, joomla, authentication

I have a joomla 2.5.20 site without any third-party extensions installed.

when i loggin to Joomla admin panel(admin permission account) via two devices (PC and Mobile )(at the same time), Every thing works fine.

But when click the logout from any one of the device, both sessions are terminated.( both devices are logged out from joomla).

Is this joomla default or Issue?

Other Informations:
Joomla Version: Joomla 2.5.20
Logged In user Group: Super Users
Joomla installed on root level.
Global Configuration: 
Cookie Domain and Cookie Path are blank
Cache: OFF - Caching disabled
Session Lifetime: 15
Session Handler: Database

Comment: Its Joomla default not an issue.

Comment: Change Session Handler from database to other one.. if you don't want this functionality.....

Comment: For security reasons, this should never be different to how it currently works

Comment: This means that if you lose your tablet you just have to logout from your desktop to destroy the session on the phone and also disable any remember me cookies that are out there.

Comment: By the way — upgrade that site ASAP that version has known security issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jobin Jose: Thanks for your Comment.

Yes, it is Joomla default and not an issue. For security reasons Joomla core doesn't allow users to do this.

If you press logout from any one of the device (same user logged in from multiple devices), the user will automatically logged out from another device also.